# Can an ASIHTTPRequest be retried?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

Is there a way to retry an ASIHTTPRequest?  I'm using custom authentication in a REST service instead of basic HTTP authentication and I would like to retry a request if the session has expired. Calling startAsynchronous a second time on a request causes an exception.  I would like to do something like this:

```
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
        if ([request responseStatusCode] == 500)
        {
            // try to login again in case token expired
            [server loginAndRetryRequest:request];
        } else {
            // parse response
        }
    }];
```

loginAndRetryRequest: will do another ASIHTTPRequest to login and when it is complete it will start the original request again from it's CompletionBlock (assuming this is possible somehow)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to make a copy of the request and then execute `-startAsynchronous` again on the copy.

Support for NSCopying protocol was added in release 1.5, which also includes automatic retry in case of timeout (selector `-setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:`.

Another option could be checking their source code to see how the automatic retry is done in case of timeout, but copying and re-issuing the request should work (that was the reason to add support for NSCopying in the first place).

Comment: Copying the request works, but only if I use setDidFinishSelector instead of setCompletionBlock.  If I use a block, it never gets called in the copy.  ASIHTTPRequest's copyWithZone doesn't seem to copy the completion block and it doesn't work when I try to do it myself either.  Maybe this is a bug?  At least I have a way to do it now.  Thanks!