# How to retry AFNetworking connection with same parameters

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I have the following code:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"parameter1":objectVariable1,@"parameter2":objectVariable2};
[MANAGER POST:@"http:www.myserver.com/somelink" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     //PROCESS RESPONSE
 }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     //PROCESS FAILURE
 }];
```

In case of failure how do I retry this connection considering the objectVariable1 & objectVariable2 can change at any point (while the connection is sent to the server) thus the same post parameters as before must be sent.
Can the parameters be obtained from `AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation` in the error branch?

Just to be sure, for example, this can be the case:
- objectVariable1 = 1
- send connection with objectVariable1 = 1
- objectVariable1 = 2
- connection fails and should retry with objectVariable1 = 1

Comment: like this : https://github.com/shaioz/AFNetworking-AutoRetry/blob/master/AFHTTPSessionManager%2BAutoRetry.m

Comment: This looks good, will look into it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220986/afnetworking-how-to-setup-requests-to-be-retried-in-the-event-of-a-timeout/39175966#39175966

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
-(void) post: (NSString *) post withParams: (NSDictionary *) params andReplies: (NSInteger) replies
{
    [MANAGER POST:post parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         //PROCESS RESPONSE
     }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         //PROCESS FAILURE
        if (replies > 0) {
            [self post: post withParams: params andReplies: replies - 1];
        }
     }];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because that was just an example. `objectVariable1` can become any value and I don't want to keep a backup of it. I wanted to know if I can somehow extract from the `operation` variable the post parameters and re-use them in a new connection.